# Azure Devops nuget artifact feed and docker

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, nuget, dockerfile

Is there a good way to create an authentication mechanism to Devops to be able to access the artifact NuGet feed? I would like to create a base image for my team that would allow them to just pull an image from our Azure Container Registry that has access to our devops nuget feed. Ideally people wouldn't have to have the same stock dockerfile code in every single project that grabs a PAT from their host build system. This would also allow us to CICD this a little more nicely.

My current solution

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

ARG IT_PAT
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS "{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\": \"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MNPIT/_packaging/MNP/nuget/v3/index.json\",\"username\": \"build\",\"password\": \"${IT_PAT}\"}]}"
RUN mkdir -p $HOME/.nuget/plugins
WORKDIR /deps

# Downloads and installs the NuGet credential plugin so we can login to the private NuGet feed
RUN curl https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/releases/download/v0.1.24/Microsoft.NetCore2.NuGet.CredentialProvider.tar.gz -L -o creds.tar.gz -s
RUN tar -xzf creds.tar.gz
RUN cp -r plugins/netcore/ ~/.nuget/plugins
```

- Stock code in every build file
- Each user configuring their environment variables with a PAT
- Passing the PAT on every build
- Does not work with an automated build system

Comment: Hi Did you get a chance to check out below workaround.How did it go?

Comment: Not yet, apologies. Moved on to another issue, but I'll try to get back to this next week

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I would like to create a base image for my team that would allow them to just pull an image from our Azure Container Registry that has access to our devops nuget feed.

You can include the credentials inside your image to achieve this, But for security concern, you've better add some extra steps or codes to pass the credentials from outside the image.

Based on your current solution, you can use the [system predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemaccesstoken) `$(System.AccessToken)` to get the security token in the azure devops CICD pipeline. Then in the docker build task, you pass the access token to the ARG IT_PAT as arguement,

`--build-arg IT_PAT=$(System.AccessToken)`

Besides using the NuGet credential plugin, You can also use the dotnet cli to add credentials to the nuget source. And then pass the `$(System.AccessToken)` in the build arguements. See below:

```
ARG PAT
COPY . .
RUN dotnet nuget add source "your-source-url" --name "source-name" --username "useless" --password "$PAT" --store-password-in-clear-text
RUN dotnet restore
```

Another workaround is to include the nuget.config in the build context. But you need to include a nuget.config file without the credentials first, and then add an extra [nuget task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) to add the credentials to the config file. Then copy the nuget.config in your docker file . See below:

Add a nuget task to run below custom command to add the credentials to the nuget.config file.

```
sources Add -Name "MyPackages" -Source "https://my.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MyPackages/nuget/v3/index.json" -username any -password $(System.AccessToken) -ConfigFile Source/Nuget.config -StorePasswordInClearText
```

Copy the nuget.config in the docker file, Donot forget to delete the nuget.config file when the restore is complete:

```
COPY *.csproj .
COPY ./nuget.config .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN rm nuget.config
```

If you are using Yaml based pipeline. You can also check out [container jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops). Then you use your private container by setting up the [container endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/container-phases?view=azure-devops#endpoints). And then you can directly use the restore tasks in your pipeline. See below example, the nuget restore task will run in your private container, and it can access to your azure feeds directly by specifying attribute `vstsFeed` to your nuget feed:

> When you specify a container in your pipeline, the agent will first fetch and start the container. Then, each step of the job will run inside the container.

```
container:
  image: myprivate/registry:ubuntu1604
  endpoint: private_dockerhub_connection

steps:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'my-azure-nuget-feed'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
```

For more information you can check out [this thread](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/6135).

Comment: I had originally considered setting up a system like this (using the CICD Access Token) but had dismissed it as exposing sensitive data. I suppose in a private ACR that's ok though. The PAT probably goes stale pretty quickly though, yes?

Comment: Yes, This token is valid for 48 hours, see [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/618929/what-is-the-scope-of-the-token-in-systemaccesstoke.html).

Answer (score 22):

### YAML

1. Run `NuGetAuthenticate` task to add `VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN` to environment variables ([more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget-authenticate?view=azure-devops#how-does-this-task-work))
2. Pass token to `Docker` task as an argument

```yaml
- task: NuGetAuthenticate@0

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: 'build docker image'
  inputs:
    command: build
    containerRegistry: 'happycodeacr'
    repository: 'hc-app-sample-api-dev'
    buildContext: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/app'
    Dockerfile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/app/src/HappyCode.Api/Dockerfile'
    arguments: '--build-arg FEED_ACCESSTOKEN=$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)'
    tags: |
      latest
      $(Build.BuildId)
```

[image: generate token by NuGetAuthenticate task]

### Dockerfile

1. Download and install artifacts provider ([more info](https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider))
2. Receive token
3. Set `VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS` environment variable with feed url and token for nuget restore process
4. Copy `NuGet.config` file
5. Run `dotnet restore`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /work

RUN curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/artifacts-credprovider/master/helpers/installcredprovider.sh  | sh
ARG FEED_ACCESSTOKEN
ENV VSS_NUGET_EXTERNAL_FEED_ENDPOINTS \
    "{\"endpointCredentials\": [{\"endpoint\":\"https://happycode.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/hc-nuget-feed/nuget/v3/index.json\", \"password\":\"${FEED_ACCESSTOKEN}\"}]}"
COPY ["NuGet.config", "./"]

COPY ["src/*/*.csproj", "./"]
RUN for projectFile in $(ls *.csproj); \
    do \
      mkdir -p ${projectFile%.*}/ && mv $projectFile ${projectFile%.*}/; \
    done
RUN dotnet restore /work/HappyCode.Api/HappyCode.Api.csproj

# further instructions
```

[image: consumption of token during Docker build task]

Comment: Don't forget to give the build agent that is building your docker container a reader role in the artifact library - especially if the artifact library is at the organization level or in a different project. Hope that saves someone a few hours of debugging!

Comment: A problem I had here, when using classical Azure DevOps build pipelines was that in Docker task "Build an image", in Build Arguments I had to pass `FEED_ACCESSTOKEN=$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)` instead of `--build-arg FEED_ACCESSTOKEN=$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)` copied from YAML.

Comment: If you've already got a token then what does the cred provider do? Can you run it in the pipeline instead of as part of the docker build?

Answer (score 3):

Adding to other replies - you can avoid modifying nuget.config in runtime and use environment variable instead.
During authentication nuget [checks environmental variables of format](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Configuration/PackageSource/PackageSourceProvider.cs#L270)

NuGetPackageSourceCredentials_'name', where 'name' is the key of the feed in the nuget.config file.

For example

`NuGetPackageSourceCredentials_MyPackages="Username=unused_but_required_by_nuget;Password=$(System.AccessToken)"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nuget.config, there is detailed guidance here:
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md#using-environment-variables-in-nugetconfig

You will need to add a nuget authenticate task before the docker build one:

```
    - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
```

And then pass the token like this:

```
    - task: Docker@2
      ..
      arguments: '--build-arg VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN="$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)"'
```

And import the ARG in your dockerfile just before your docker restore:

```
..
ARG VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN
..
```

You can then use the token in your config file like this:

```
..
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <feed-key>
            <add key="Username" value="any" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN%" />
        </feed-key>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
..
```